# save the state of my togglebutton after return in the same activity or restart application

Tags: android

everybody! I try to save the state of my ToggleButton. In fact, i would like to have the same state after user restart his application or return in this activity.

But for example when i return in my previous activity and then when i re-return in my activity where is my ToggleButton, i see that the ToggleButton status is not registered. If anyone can help me?

Like you can see, i use setDefaults to save the state of my ToggleButton and getDefaults to recover it.

```
public class OnOff extends Activity {

    ToggleButton toggle1;
    ToggleButton toggle2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.on_off);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();

        toggle1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ontoggle1);
        toggle1.setChecked(getDefaults("etatToggle",this));
        setDefaults("etatToggle", toggle1.isChecked(), this);
    }


    //Fonction appelée pour enregistrer en mémoire, ici en l'occurence l'état du ToggleButton: true ou false
    public static void setDefaults(String key, Boolean value, Context context)
    {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    //Fonction appelée pour récupérer ce qui a été saisi en mémoire
    public static Boolean getDefaults(String key, Context context)
    {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getBoolean(key, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();

    toggle1.setChecked(getDefaults("etatToggle",this));
}


@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();

    setDefaults("etatToggle", toggle1.isChecked(), this);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Logician , i have done it in onPause() & in onResume() too. It work correctly, thank you very much ;)

Comment: @forgive90 You don't need it in onPause() or onResume(), because the state of the toggle button should be retained in memory.

Comment: hi, i came back because it worked fine but now it does not work anymore... when i click to turn my togglebutton in "On", when i return to my previous activity & then when i arrive in my togglebutton activity, it is "OFF"... do you have any idea?

Comment: Try doing it in onResume() and onPause() then.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are calling the following

```
    setDefaults("etatToggle", toggle1.isChecked(), this);
```

in `onCreate()`, everytime you start your application the `ToggleButton` is checked irrespective of the previous state of the `ToggleButton` when the application was closed. So this line of code should be placed as follows-

```
    toggle1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

           setDefaults("etatToggle", toggle1.isChecked(), OnOff.this);
    }
});
```

so that the state of the `ToggleButton` is saved when you click it and thereby the `ToggleButton` will retain its previous state when the application is started again.

Comment: Thank you my friend but the correct answer is the previous comment but thank you very much for your help

Comment: Hey but even this works!! Try it out as an alternative approach :)

Comment: Actually the accepted answer has a flaw. In case your app crashes after you made some state changes to your ToggleButton, then the last state won't be saved. Try it out :)